Identify predictors for clustering output?
I have a dataset with variables collected years ago, and many variables collected this year as outcome variables. I want to combine all the variables collected this year to get one outcome, e.g. reflecting overall functioning, to reduce number of outcomes to one. This was possible with K-means clustering, giving a two cluster solution.
Now I want to investigate which variables collected years ago are predictors for the outcome (e.g., overall functioning), testing several machine learning approaches (logistic regression, SVM, decision trees, etc).
Is it a feasible question to attempt to predict cluster outcome?
I understand that initializing the clusters on the complete (outcomes) dataset and then splitting into train/test causes some data leakage. Is this a big problem, or is there any way to tackle this problem? I am afraid that clustering in the training/test set separately will not provide the same clusters.

It'd help to know how results will be used. Do you actually want to predict yet unseen outcomes in this year? Do you want to use this to predict next year's outcomes (how exactly)? When predicting future outcomes, does it suffice for what you want to do with the predictions to have a binary cluster prediction?

If you split into training/test, you could cluster the training set and then specify a suitable loss function that compares the actual (non-clustered) outcome in the test set somehow with the predicted cluster. The easiest way to do this is to ask how close the outcome is to the mean of the cluster to which it was predicted, but whether this is a good idea depends on what use exactly you will make of the precitions

@ChristianHennig the data is from a longitudinal follow-up study and I have the outcomes for all participants. I want to say something about which predictors seem to be relevant for better/worse functioning (cluster 1 or 2) at the follow-up

"I understand that initializing the clusters on the complete (outcomes) dataset and then splitting into train/test causes some data leakage. Is this a big problem, or is there any way to tackle this problem? I am afraid that clustering in the training/test set separately will not provide the same clusters." You are right about this, and this is a problem. (Sorry, this doesn't tell you what to do, but having your intuition confirmed is maybe already something...)

If you want groups with the straight interpretation of "better/worse functioning", can't you just define them based on your knowledge of the variables in a manner that doesn't do it automatically from the data? In that way it wouldn't be a problem that the clustering changes with adding or removing data.

You may also try to aggregate your outcome variables into a single meaningful index and then use standard regression techniques. (In fact also multivariate regression techniques exist, and you can consider them for this as well.)
